basedn empty string even when specified in modsenabled ldap
I'm trying to test if radius is working properly with ldap.
I am testing with NTRadPing and noted the following.
In mods-enabled I have added the following to the ldap file (just showing the base_dn line).
ldap {
    base_dn = 'DC=ad,DC=examplename,DC=com'
}

This basedn is directly extracted from what I have found within the rergarding Active Directory with the line distinguisedName so there can't be a problem there I believe.
Now when testing it with NTRadPing and opening freeradius with parameter -X I see that it is not using the basedn and instead shows an empty string.
rlm_ldap (ldap): Reserved connection (0)
(0) ldap: Performing unfiltered search in "", scope "sub"
(0) ldap: Waiting for search result...
(0) ldap: The specified DN wasn't found
(0) ldap: Search returned no results
rlm_ldap (ldap): Released connection (0)

I have tried to find solutions but have not been able to. Is there a logic solution to this problem?
Any info is appreciated. Later I want to apply it to switches so only devices that are part of the domain can use it.
Thanks.
I have tried adding a OU before DC but that also doesn't change the problem.
